# How to properly display price for downloadable product

Tags: magento2, blocks, price

There are a quite a lot of classes responsible for displaying prices, as well as tutorials about it.

How to display just simple price for downloadable product in custom block/template? Is there any preferable way? I think it would be nice to include some models if needed for DI of my block.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the price from a product is through the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getFinalPrice()` method. This method caches the price in the model once it has been calculated, and queries the price model if it has not been calculated yet.

If you already have a product model instance, you can just use that. If not, the current product can be accessed through the registry, or loaded through an instance of the `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`, so long as you have the ID for it.

Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense!

Comment: the problem is not to obtain value of price - I know these methods - question is about displaying it.

Final price displays a lot of zeros and I don't feel the treating it as normal integer and just trim zero and add sign of `$` is proper way to display price.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found nice way (not sure if best one) in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:350`:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getPriceRender();

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'include_container' => true,
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                'list_category_page' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render
 */
protected function getPriceRender()
{
    return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
}
```

Using first method in template we can get nice price string. What is more this one can be placed in any blocks as it only dependence is from `AbstractBlock` (`$this->getLayout()`).